# Authentication in affectiva via API

Tags: affdex-sdk

i want to use affectiva API, for it I must send token with username and password.

From [documentations](http://developer.affectiva.com/apioverview/):

> Our APIs use HTTP Basic Access Authentication to authenticate clients. HTTP Basic Authentication relies on a TLS transport to ensure that the client credentials cannot be seen by a third party, so all API communications must be transmitted over a TLS-protected channel. Please ensure that your Index Service API begins with “https” before using it.

**But I can't find SIGN UP button** how i can receive username and password?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the moment you will need to contact sales@affectiva.com to get access to EaaS or the Affdex MR products.