# Emotion as a Service API credentials

Tags: affdex-sdk

I am interested in trying out the Affectiva Emotion as a Service API using the cloud. I am not sure how to obtain the credentials such as the username and the password needed to use the service. What is the procedure to obtain an account and the credentials needed for the API?

Comment: You can find your answer in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41350983/4686445) post.